# isset to check existence of session is not working in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm trying to build a simple website with a login and signup system for my school project.

Login procedure is fine but there is a problem in signup system. I've planned to provide Welcome IDs to Students. They will use those welcome IDs to register on website. During Signup when a user will provide correct welcome ID, only then he/she can proceed. I'll put all sign up data into my database and use session variables to temporarily store user's sign up status(welcome Id, email etc.). I'll assign a 16 digit sign_up_auth to corresponding welcome ID and store it in client side Cookies.

In case the user closed the browser during sign up process and session is destroyed then I'll use the sign_up_auth to regenerate session variables for user so that he/she can resume sign up. The problem is too complicated.

At the top of every page of my sign_up system I've used some code to detect if a session exist or not. If a session does't exist I'll redirect them to session regeneration page that'll use sign_up_auth cookies and redirect them to previous step of sign up. But if a session exist and user had completed previous steps of sign up then he/she can proceed on current page. I'm using session variables to detect how many steps of sign up had been completed by user(1 or 2 or 3..there are 3 of total).

Okay, Now see...When I'm reopening browser(after closing it during sign up)
it is doing both of things, first It is redirecting me to sign_up_auth page and secondly it is using it's own code to redirect which should only happen if a session exist.

I've tried almost Everything. Used Different Version of PHP. Cleared my browser data. Restarted localhost server many times. I've seen a lot of articles and guides but none of them could help me.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["sign_up_level"])) {header("location: reg_switch.php");} /*THIS IS EXECUTING*/
///////////////////////////////////////
if ($_SESSION["sign_up_level"] == 404) { $_SESSION["redir_from_provide"] = true; header("location: registration.php"); exit(); }
if ($_SESSION["sign_up_level"] == 2) { $_SESSION["redir_from_provide"] = true; header("location: reg_verify_email.php"); exit(); } /*THIS IS ALSO EXECUTING, AND IT'S PROBLEM */
if ($_SESSION["sign_up_level"] == 3) { $_SESSION["redir_from_provide"] = true; header("location: final_registration.php"); exit(); }
///////////////////////////////////////
$x = time();
$ZZZ = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $_SESSION["session_exp"]);
$HHH = strtotime($ZZZ);
if ($x > $HHH) { $_SESSION["sign_up_level"] = 404; $_SESSION["redir_from_provide"] = true; header("location: registration.php"); exit(); }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////BELOW IS THE CODE FROM THE FILE THAT WILL VERIFY SIGN_UP_AUTH COOKIES///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_COOKIE["sign_up_auth"]) && empty($_SESSION["sign_up_level"]))
{//MAIN_111
    //Retrive data from Cookies
    $sign_up_auth = $_COOKIE["sign_up_auth"];
    // Server Variables
    $DBhost = "localhost";
    $DBuser = "root";
    $DBpswd = 'PASSWORD';
    $DB = "testDB";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($DBShost, $DBSuser, $DBSpswd, $DB);
    // Look for Existence of auth Cookie
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("Select * from sign_up_table where cookie_auth = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $sign_up_auth);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $resultset[] = $row; } // Form an Array of $result

    // Verify Existance
    $x = time();
    $ZZZ = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $resultset[0]["cookie_exp"]);
    $HHH = strtotime($ZZZ);
    if ($result->num_rows == 1)
    {
        if ($x < $HHH) // reg_auth is not expired
                {
                    $_SESSION["welcome_id"] = $resultset[0]["welcome_id"]; //2nd
                    $_SESSION["session_exp"] = $resultset[0]["cookie_exp"]; //3rd
                    /////
                    if ($resultset[0]["sign_up_level"] === 1) { $_SESSION["sign_up_level"] = 1; $_SESSION["redir_from_switch"] = "from switch to provide."; header("location: reg_provide_email.php"); } //Provide Email Page
                    if ($resultset[0]["sign_up_level"] === 2) { $_SESSION["sign_up_level"] = 2; $_SESSION["redir_from_switch"] = "from switch to verify"; $_SESSION["sign_up_email"] = $resultset[0]["sign_up_email"]; header("location: reg_verify_email.php"); } //Enter OTP Page
                    if ($resultset[0]["sign_up_level"] === 3) { $_SESSION["sign_up_level"] = 3; $_SESSION["redir_from_switch"] = "from switch to final."; $_SESSION["sign_up_email"] = $resultset[0]["sign_up_email"]; header("location: final_registration.php"); } //Final Registration Page
                    /////
                } else { $_SESSION["sign_up_level"] = 404; $_SESSION["redir_from_switch"] = "Session_Cleared:-Cookie Expired"; header("location: registration.php");} //expired
    } else { $_SESSION["sign_up_level"] = 404; $_SESSION["redir_from_switch"] = "Session_Cleared:-Cookie Auth Invalid"; header("location: registration.php");} // cookies auth invalid
} else { $_SESSION["sign_up_level"] = 404; $_SESSION["redir_from_switch"] = "Session_Cleared:-Cookie not found"; header("location: registration.php");} //cookie not found
?>
```

I was expecting that It'll redirect me to reg_switch.php(see 2nd line of code)
But it doing both of thing...

for example I'm on 2nd step of signup(verify email by giving OTP) and accidentally I closed browser. On reopening it takes me to right place but there are 2 redirection to that page. (one from reg_provide_email and other from reg_switch). That's almost not possible. I'm sure that I'm doing somewhere a mistake.

Comment: Always use `exit;` after `header("Location: ...);` to prevent it from executing further after the header call.

Comment: There are no operators bewteen isset($_COOKIE["sign_up_auth"]) empty($_SESSION["sign_up_level"])

Comment: @DylanKas , that's mistake while asking question. I'm using && as a operator between them. But problem doesn't solved. Please Help me out. And thanks !

Comment: @Qirel , is it necessary to use exit; after header(location:....) ? I think it could be skipped.

Comment: It is needed. `header("Location: ...."); exit;`

Comment: @Qirel thanks for info, but doing so doesn't solved my problem.

Comment: I've also tried to relpace isset($_SESSION["sign_up_level"] with isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]) but nothing happens to solve my problem.